# Help to modify RWD trans-axle bearing design

Tags: transmission, axle, bearing, custom

My project car is RWD with trans-axles running inside independent housing sleeves, as in the diagram below. The problem I have is that each axle use only one weird, fat, double track, axial bearing :) in the outside which takes all the load and in/outs. I'm having problems trying to find such bearing, or something like it. When one got damaged, I got told by other owner that a single track can be installed, by adding a spacer washer underneath it so it fits correctly. The issue is that as it is not axial, they get literally shattered up in months: single track/no axial, can't take the swivel load, since the axle "floats" on it, swiveling up and down for some degrees.

[image]

Now I think about adding a second single track bearing but at the inside, the side near the gearbox, as the diagram below. The idea is to insert a seat for the bearing, then put it there, and then the drive shaft and make the axle "stiff" inside its housing pipe.

Other (related) question would be:

- for the inside: ball bearing or roller bearing?
- for the outside:  Normal bearing or tapped bearing?

I can't use CV joints since it will require changing a lot of stuff and no budged for that.

Asked a few guys and told me, why not? Still I want to run the question here and get some comments!

[image]

Comment: any one? Comments are welcome!